# On SE iOS mobile app, it always switches back to 'active' questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, sorting, question-lists

I typically set all stack exchange sites to 'Newest' as I want to see the newest questions. However, multiple times a day it switches back to 'Active' by itself, and I find myself reading questions I already know (until I realize it). It's just a pain.

Why does the App insist on switching back to 'Active Questions'? And when does it do it? I cannot actively produce it, logging out and in or killing the app does not do it, but some hours later it happened again, for random pages (not for all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.0.2.

We were saving the sort any time a new question list appeared, even if it was a temporary sort.  So if you visited questions tagged [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app), the app would save that as your last used sort.  Then when you visited the site again, it would see your preferred sort no longer existed and would default back to active.

Now, the app will only save the sort if you explicitly change it with the picker and will not save temporary sorts.

You can try this change when it's built by [becoming a beta tester](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).

Comment: I accepted the beta testing invite, and did test. The error seems gone in the 1.5.0.2 build and also in the release candidate. I am not sure _how_ to report this formally (or if you care at all), but this build fixes it, thanks.